# How backup softwares add hotkeys (say F11) to computer boot options?

Tags: windows, boot

My friend installed a nice backup software (named [Acronis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronis)) for me that has a feature called startup recovery manager. Basically it allows me to boot into (a bootable media version of) the software by pressing F11 during computer startup; no USB or DVD required!

I was super curious about this feature so I searched a lot but only [found a tutorial](http://faizalsalih.blogspot.com/p/creating-hidden-recovery-partition.html) that achieved this by creating a hidden partition and useing grub4dos and Clonezilla. I followed that tutorial successfully on my VM but I don't think Acronis creates a hidden partition.

- Can someone please give me some hints/links on exactly how acronis
  does that?
- Suppose I have an iso image of acronis, can I add F11 to boot options
  without using a dedicated partition or DVD/USB?

I have Windows 8.1 x86 (Bios/MBR).

Comment: Yes, Acronis actually does create a partition.  The Acronis ISO isn’t enough you need a licensed legitimate installation of Acronis installed.  If you already have 4 partitions then you won’t be able to do what you want due to the limitations of MBR

Comment: @Ramhound wow, really? silly me! :)